# Sorting Array of Categories

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm attempting to sort the following array for use in a foreach loop that outputs the latest post from each of the categories of goose-creek, sleepy-creek, and fobr.

I want to sort this array by the post date, but I'm somewhat confused on how to accomplish this. Would it be better to just add multiple categories to the WP_Query args and remove the foreach loop?

```
$feed_sources = array('goose-creek','sleepy-creek','fobr');


foreach ($feed_sources as $feed) {
$args = array('category_name' => $feed, 'posts_per_page' => 1);
$show = new WP_Query($args);
$show->the_post();
```

Comment: Do you want to output a post from **each** of those categories? Or do you just want to output the three most recent posts, and it doesn't matter which category they're in, as long as they belong to one of those three?

Comment: Latest post from **each**

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses an associative array and outputs the category as the key and the date as an integer into the value.

Arsort() then sorts the array from high to low

```
$feed_sources = array('goose-creek','sleepy-creek','fobr');
$dates_array = array();

foreach ($feed_sources as $feed) {
  $args = array('category_name' => $feed, 'posts_per_page' => 1);
  $show = new WP_Query($args);
  $show->the_post();
  $dates_array[$feed] = the_date('YmdHis','','',false);
}

arsort($dates_array);
$ordered_sources = array_keys($dates_array);

foreach ($ordered_sources as $feed) {
  $args = array('category_name' => $feed, 'posts_per_page' => 1);
  $show = new WP_Query($args);
  $show->the_post();
```